# What is the unique morphism for the coequalizer in the category of groups?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

By wikipedia:

> If $f,g: X \rightarrow Y$ are parallel homomorphisms between groups, then $e: Y \rightarrow Y / S$ is the coequalizer, where $S$ is the normal closure of the set $\{f(x)g(x)^{-1} : x \in X\}$.

My the requirements of a coequalizer, for every $h : Y \rightarrow D$ homomorphism between groups there exists an $h' : Y / S \rightarrow D$ such that $h' \circ e = h$ and $S=\{z_1^{n_1}z_2^{n_2} \dots \in Y:z_i = y^{-1}f(x)g(x)^{-1}y \text{ for some $y \in Y$ and $x \in X$ }\}$

What is $h'$ here?  It looks like it would be $y + S \rightarrow h(y)$ but I'm having trouble showing this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: make it $yS\mapsto h(y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not for *every* homomorphism $h\colon Y \to D$, but just those $h$ for which $hf = hg$.  In particular, for $x \in X$ this means $h(f(x)) = h(g(x))$ so $h(f(x)g(x)^{-1}) = 1$.  As the kernel is normal this implies $S$ is contained in the kernel of $h$ and therefore passing to the quotient gives a unique homomorphism $Y/S \to D$ defined by
$$yS \mapsto h(y).$$